# Why does the code produce the following result?

Tags: java, oop, inheritance, polymorphism, inner-classes

I'm puzzled and a little bit wasted by the next snippet. I guess it is all because of static inner class and scope of the function of class A1 which is called.

If you have a explanation-in-details, please share it!

```
public class Main {
    static class A1 {
        private void f() { System.out.println("A1");}
    }

    static class A2 extends A1 {
        public void f() {System.out.println("A2");}
    }

    static class A3 extends A2 {
        public void f() {System.out.println("A3");}
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        A1 a1 = new A1();
        a1.f();
        a1 = new A2();
        a1.f();
        a1 = new A3();
        a1.f();
    }
}
```

Expected:

```
A1
A2
A3
```

Actual:

```
A1
A1
A1
```

Comment: `private` methods are not inherited.

Comment: The `f()` method is overloaded from A1, not overridden in this situation

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels I think you mean that it is hidden.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The method `f()` in `A1` is marked `private`.  This means that it is *not* inherited by `A2` or `A3`.  This means that polymorphism will not find the overriding methods `f()` in `A2` or `A3`.  However, because `A1` is a nested class, the enclosing `Main` class still has access to it, so it compiles.  The result is that `A1` is printed 3 times.

You could see the error if you attempted to place an `@Override` annotation on `f()` in `A2`.  If you change `f()` to `public`, `protected`, or no access modifier ("package access") in `A1`, then `f()` would get inherited as you expect, so that the output would be as you expect, with `A1`, `A2`, and `A3` being outputted.

Comment: `protected` is enough, don't need `public` modifier

Comment: @aBnormaLz True; I've also added the case without an access modifier - package access.